# History.js: I just want to change the URL, no need to manage history

Tags: javascript, html, history.js

I am using HTML5 to change the URL of my page once it loads. This is because the real URL shows a long cacheID which I do not want to display. I use the HTML5 History API to change the URL of the current window and now the user can share and bookmark the URL without the annoying cacheID.

This is the code I am using, and it executes when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.history.pushState(null, "Title", "/url");
</script>
```

After it executes, I see in my address bar: http://mydomain.com/url

This is good.

Now I would like to use History.js so that my site can support users with older browsers.

How do I go about it?

First, I include this:

```
<script src="http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then I put the same code I used previously

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.history.pushState(null, "Title", "/url");
</script>
```

It does not work. Because I think I have to create new objects, but I am not sure how to go about that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I have just added: 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

But it still does not work in IE8

Comment: Included before or after history.js? Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: What error do you see? Does it work in other browsers than IE8?

Comment: I've included history.js and jquery.min.js. Do I have to declare a var before using it? As of now I am executing window.history.pushState(null, "Title", "/url");

Comment: You need to include jquery.min.js before history.js. No need to declare anything I think. What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: It works in IE9. Thanks! The problem was that I had to include jquery.min.js, and I have to use a capital H when I use the History function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you've forgot to include jQuery, since you're including a version of History.js that's built for this. Without including jQuery before jquery.history.js, the latter will fail.

**EDIT**:

After including jQuery *before* jquery.history.js, do `window.History.pushState(null, "Title", "/url");`. Notice that History starts with a capital H, this is important.

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUHcz/) for how to use History.js. I've only tried it with Chromium, but see if that works in IE8 for you.